# SQLite3 Error in Firefox Extension

Tags: javascript, sqlite, firefox-addon

I am writing a Firefox extension that will get the current browser's handle and write it to a sqlite database. My whole code is:

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm");

let file = FileUtils.getFile("ProfD", ["testing.sqlite"]);
let dbConn = Services.storage.openDatabase(file);

var browserWindow = Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser');
if (!browserWindow) {
    throw new Error('No browser window found');
}

var baseWindow = browserWindow.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
                              .getInterface(Ci.nsIWebNavigation)
                              .QueryInterface(Ci.nsIDocShellTreeItem)
                              .treeOwner
                              .QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
                              .getInterface(Ci.nsIBaseWindow);

var hwndString = baseWindow.nativeHandle;

Components.utils.import('resource://gre/modules/ctypes.jsm');

var user32 = ctypes.open('user32.dll');

/* http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633539%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
 * BOOL WINAPI SetForegroundWindow(
 *   __in_ HWND hWnd
 * );
 */
var SetForegroundWindow = user32.declare('SetForegroundWindow', ctypes.winapi_abi,
    ctypes.bool, // return BOOL
    ctypes.voidptr_t // HWND
);

var hwnd 
hwnd = ctypes.voidptr_t(ctypes.UInt64(hwndString));
var rez_SetForegroundWindow = SetForegroundWindow(hwnd);

console.log('hwnd: ', hwnd.toString());
dbConn.createStatement("INSERT INTO tblHandles(handle) VALUES("+ hwnd +")");
//dbConn.executeSimpleSQL("INSERT INTO tblHandles(handle) VALUES("+ hwnd+")");

user32.close();
```

I am getting the error:

```
NS_ERROR_FAILURE: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [mozIStorageConnection.createStatement]
```

at the line:

```
dbConn.createStatement("INSERT INTO tblHandles(handle) VALUES("+ hwnd +")");
```

Both createStatement and executeSimpleSQL throw the same error and I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the statement expects a string, you are passing it an object, specifically you are passing it `CData {  }` which is what the line `hwnd = ctypes.voidptr_t(ctypes.UInt64(hwndString));` does. So instead of `dbConn.createStatement("INSERT INTO tblHandles(handle) VALUES("+ hwnd +")");` do this:

```
dbConn.createStatement("INSERT INTO tblHandles(handle) VALUES("+ hwndString +")");
```

Also jsctypes is cool but I think it would be better to use only when absolutely necessary, as I think the perf is slightly worse. So there isnt a need for using it to focus the window. Instead just do `browserWindow..focus();`

NOTE:
Also I see you mixing Components.utils with Ci are you defining what Ci is? If you are why don't you just define Cu up there too and do Cu instead of Components.utils.

Comment: Cool @TravisStauffer but make sure when you read from the database, to make sure you do `ctypes.voidptr_t(ctypes.UInt64` again on read value from table

Comment: I am using a c# program to read the stored handle so I am converting it back to hex over there. It's working perfectly now.